# Setup Symfony2 and Postgresql on OS X 10.10 Yosemite?

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I can't found a way to setup Symfony with a postgresql database on OS X 10.10 (clean install). Here is what I have done:

1) Install PHP 5.6 from Liip (specially built for Symfony): http://php-osx.liip.ch/

2) Install Postgres.app: http://postgresapp.com/

3) Install Symfony: http://symfony.com/

4) Setup my parameters.yml

```
parameters:
    database_driver: pdo_pgsql
    database_host: 127.0.0.1
    database_port: 5432
    database_name: bachelor
    database_user: username
    database_password: ~
```

I have created the DB, verified that I have the right PHP cli, the right pgql cli, etc.

I have created a bundle in Symfony and some entities (no errors here, it works with MySQL).

But when I launch any command to interact with the DB like "`php app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql`", I have this error:

```
[PDOException]                                     
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2006] MySQL server has gone away

[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]  
Warning: PDO::__construct(): MySQL server has gone away
```

But why? I don't use a MySQL server...

Does someone have any solution?

Thanks!

Comment: May I recommend something like a `VagrantBox` that is a preconfigured VM distrubtion of linux that has all of these things already taken care of for you? [Here's the gifthub project](https://github.com/Wesseldr/vagrant-symfony-psql) and here's [the link to the vagrant documentation](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/getting-started/index.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you show us your /app/config/config.yml ? please

Did you change the dbal connection value ?

```
# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: pgsql
        connections:
            #Postgresql
            pgsql:
                driver:   "%database_driver%"
                host:     "%database_host%"
                port:     "%database_port%"
                dbname:   "%database_name%"
                user:     "%database_user%"
                password: "%database_password%"
                charset:  UTF8
```

Comment: # Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   pdo_mysql
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        charset:  UTF8

Comment: Do I need to change the driver here?

Comment: Yes replace the driver `pdo_mysql` by `pdo_pgsql`.